# How to add relative layout to a View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-view

I have a custom Relative Layout and added a button to it

```
 RelativeLayout rel_layout = new RelativeLayout(mcontext);
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rel_param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
 rel.setLayoutParams(rel_param);

 Button b = new Button(mcontext);
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 b.setLayoutParams(params);
 b.setText("Test");
 rel_layout.addView(b);
```

Now, I want this Relative layout to be added to a View. My View Class looks like this is

```
public class CustomView extends View {

Context mcontext;

public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    this.mcontext = context;
}
```

}

and in the Main Activity I am calling this view in my setConentView()

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new CustomView(this));
}
```

}

So now on the Screen I should have the relative layout with the button in it. I should not use any XMl's.

I need help in how to add the dynamic relative created to be added to my CustomView class

Hope I have explained my problem clearly.

Comment: add your custom view to relative layout

Comment: i am looking for the other way round.. i want  the relative layout to be added in the CustomView class

Answer (score 0):

Your custom view has to extend a `ViewGroup`, not a `View`.

Comment: what is your custom view supposed to fo?

Comment: Yes agreed. I will extend a ViewGroup. because I want to place 3 relative layouts one below the other inside a customView .. and use the customView class in my setContentView()

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to do that. `RelativeLayout` is a `ViewGroup`. `ViewGroup` is a `View` that can hold one or more `View`s as children. You should implement your own `ViewGroup` instead of `View`.
You can find a tutorial for implementing custom `ViewGroup` here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html

Also, I'd like to suggest that you might actually want to place `RelativeLayout` directly on your `Activity` and place some customized widgets on top of it along with the button you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this 
custom_view.xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relCustomView"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:padding="5dp">

</RelativeLayout>

public class CustomView extends View{
    private Context context;

    public  CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context=context;
    }
    public View getCustomView(){
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_view,null,false);

        RelativeLayout relCustomView = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.relCustomView);

        Button b = new Button(context);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        b.setLayoutParams(params);
        b.setText("Test");
        relCustomView.addView(b);
        return v;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new CustomView(this).getCustomView());
}
```

Comment: this is good but I have a restriction that I cannot use an xml because I have to deliver a .jar file